# Room Database Update a column (CHeckbox)

Tags: database, kotlin, checkbox, sql-update, android-room

I recently started programming apps and don't have that much experience yet. Especially not with database programming.

I have a shoppinglist and want to check items.

I still can't manage to update the column. I found a few things on the internet but can't put it all together. For example, I don't know how to get the id from the item. Or do I need the ID at all?

I ask for help. Thanks!

Entity:

```
@Entity
data class ShoppingList(
    val Name: String,
    val Einheit: String,
    val Menge: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isChecked", defaultValue = "0")
    val isChecked: Boolean,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingListDao {

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsertItem(items: ShoppingList)

    @Query("UPDATE ShoppingList SET isChecked = :isChecked WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun updateItem(isChecked: Boolean, id: Int)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteItem(items: ShoppingList)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ShoppingList ORDER BY Name ASC")
    fun getItemsOrderByName(): Flow<List<ShoppingList>>

}
```

Event:

```
sealed interface ShoppingListEvent{
    object SaveItem: ShoppingListEvent
    data class SetName(val Name: String): ShoppingListEvent
    data class SetEinheit(val Einheit: String): ShoppingListEvent
    data class SetMenge(val Menge: String): ShoppingListEvent
    data class SetCheckbox(val isChecked: Boolean): ShoppingListEvent
    object ShowDialog: ShoppingListEvent
    object HideDialog: ShoppingListEvent
    data class SortItems(val sortType: SortType): ShoppingListEvent
    data class DeleteItem(val items: ShoppingList): ShoppingListEvent
}
```

State:

```
data class ShoppingListState (
    val items: List<ShoppingList> = emptyList(),
    val Name: String = "",
    val Einheit: String = "",
    val Menge: String = "",
    val isChecked: Boolean = false,
    val isAddingItem: Boolean = false,
    val sortType: SortType = SortType.Name
)
```

Viewmodel:

```
class ShoppingListViewModel(
    private val  dao: ShoppingListDao
): ViewModel() {

    private val _sortType = MutableStateFlow(SortType.Name)
    private val _items = _sortType
        .flatMapLatest { sortType ->
            when(sortType) {
                SortType.Name -> dao.getItemsOrderByName()
            }
        }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(ShoppingListState())
    val state = combine(_state, _sortType, _items) { state, sortType, items ->
        state.copy(
            items = items,
            sortType = sortType
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), ShoppingListState())


    fun onEvent(event: ShoppingListEvent){
        when(event){

            ....

            is ShoppingListEvent.SetCheckbox -> {
                
                //I don't know what to do here. 
                
                val isChecked = state.value.isChecked

                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.updateItem(isChecked)
                }

            ...

            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

And the Checkbox:

```
Checkbox(
    checked = state.isChecked,
    onCheckedChange ={
          onEvent(ShoppingListEvent.SetCheckbox(it))
    }
)
```

I tried a few things. Sometimes nothing happens and sometimes all Items got checked.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly there's list of items, each item has the checkbox. If that's the case, then checkbox's state should depend on the item it belongs to.

```
Checkbox(
    checked = state.items[itemIndex].isChecked,
    onCheckedChange ={
          onEvent(ShoppingListEvent.SetCheckbox(it,  
          !state.items[itemIndex].isChecked))
    }
)
```

To update single item's state you need to pass an ID of the item being check.

```
fun onEvent(event: ShoppingListEvent, itemId : Int){
    when(event){       ...

        is ShoppingListEvent.SetCheckbox -> {
            
            viewModelScope.launch {
                dao.updateItem(isChecked, itemID)
            }

        ...

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Now another problem arises.
I use navigation and I get the following error:

" Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2<ShoppingListEvent, Int, Unit> but (ShoppingListEvent) -> Unit was expected"

MainActivity:
`Navigation(state = state, onEvent = viewModel::onEvent)`

Navigation:
`fun Navigation(
    state: ShoppingListState,
    onEvent: (ShoppingListEvent) -> Unit
){
..
composable(route = Screen.MainScreen.route){
            MainScreen(navController = navController, state = state, onEvent = onEvent)
        }`
Viewmodel:
`fun onEvent(event: ShoppingListEvent, id: Int){`

Comment: I see that the Type at the Navigation is missmatching but I don't know what  the correct type is.

Comment: You need to change function definition since we changed one in ViewModel.  onEvent: (ShoppingListEvent, Int) -> Unit )